# Are there any good UIScrollView Tutorials on the net?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiscrollview

Any good links are highly appreciated! This goes to community wiki.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Some good samples with the basic functionalities covered

- [very simple uiscrollview demo](http://halmueller.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/a-very-simple-uiscrollview-demo/)
- [Scrolling](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Scrolling/index.html)
- [UiScrollViewTutorial](http://www.vimeo.com/1642150)
- [implementing tap to zoom in uiscrollview on an iphone](http://jonathanwatmough.com/2008/12/implementing-tap-to-zoom-in-uiscrollview-on-an-iphone/)
- [multiple virtual pages in uiscrollview](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html)

Not to mention:

- [stackoverflow UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UIScrollView)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a new one:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content#more-10518

Answer (score 3):

My article on two advanced UIScrollView techniques (+ sample code): [github.com/andreyvit/ScrollingMadness/](http://github.com/andreyvit/ScrollingMadness/):

1. Emulating Photo Library-style paging+zooming+scrolling.
2. Programmatically zooming UIScrollView.

Answer (score 3):

It's my blog but it may be useful for the beginners  [Tutorial for creating UIScrollview Programmatically](http://unconditionalloop.blogspot.com/2011/04/uiscrollview-programmatically.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial perfect for my situation. I didn't need any zooming effect. I want a large content holding subviews.

[uiscrollview-examples](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/uiscrollview-examples/)