# how to use UISCROLLVIEW?

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview

i have to use `UIScrollView` , I've 5 uiimageview and i should to scroll them, but i don't know how to do!Anyone can help me? or tell me a good tutorial where i can learn fast all
things about uiscrollview,

thank you guys

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// create a new scroll view and add to window
UIScrollView * scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

For tutorials check out this question [Are there any good UIScrollView Tutorials on the net? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/820748/468724)