# Auto position sibling UIViews

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have 4 UIViews stacked in a UIScrollView.

When any one of the UIViews are tapped, I want that particular view to expand and show some more content and this would mean the sibling views below the selected view has to push themselves down.

I could have used UITableView but there are all kinds of weird stuff happening when you change the row heights dynamically which is why I chose this fallback.

Can I use autoresizingmask to do this ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your question Answer is not so simple,you Need to use Different Logic Means You know how Much Width and Hight your Each view have after Clicking on it and then you can pass the reference of View to setContentSize of Scrollview.here is some tutorial which solved my problem when i was putting some run time data in Scrollview.

[link](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/)

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820557/are-there-any-good-uiscrollview-tutorials-on-the-net)

Hope it will be helpfull for you.