# highly interactive iOS app in html5+jquery or core xcode

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I want to design an iOS app, which is **highly interactive + animated sliding views**.
i have option like:
1) core xCode
2) HTML5 + jquery mobile + CSS
3) phone gap

but im not sure which platform is best ?? my requirements are:
**1) app should be fast to create and easy to upgrade and maintain.**
2) in future i can extend it to multiple mobile platform(i know ..its possible with phonegap but due to study time im tyring to put it aside and also this is my second priority. so please dont consider it.)

I dont know whether i can design full app in HTML5 + jquery 
however i want to make it possible in xCode because its native to iOS development.

**Please guide me through. and also good to have some good references of creating highly interactive iOS app's with best and simplest way.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Writing highly interactive apps with sliding and animated views is not going to be easy no matter what approach you take.  It seems to me that from your options, you will need to choose what you want want most between interactivity/quality, speed, and portability.

> -Objective C will give you top quality/interactivity as the native language and it sounds like you are ready to use it, so that would be
>   speed too.  However, porting may be more difficult later
>
> -HTML 5 will be easy to port and it sounds like you are ready for that too, but I don't think you have as much power as with objective C
>
> -I don't know much about Phone Gap, but I do know it will mean portability and I think it gives you more power than HTML, but it
>   sounds like you will need to study for that one and therefore
>   sacrifice speed.

If you happen to choose Objective C, here are some resources to get you started:

-Look at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820557/are-there-any-good-uiscrollview-tutorials-on-the-net) for scrolling
-As for animation, there are many different methods, the simplest would be combining [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes)
with [This](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html).  (Doesn't have to be gif's for the second one, personally I prefer png's)