# panning and zooming for UIImage view based on touches moved in UIview( subview of UIImage view)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am working on a white board application. I have an UIimage view and this view contains a UIview as sub view. this  UIview is being used for intermediate operation like(during drawing a rectangle ... touch move period) after touch ended finaly i am drawing it on UIImage view. Now  i have to pan and zoom this UIimage view if a get a  single touch for pan and two fingure touch for zoom on UIview and this touch point does not lies on  any  of the drawn component on UIImage view . please suggest me  how  to  do  that ...??

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking to do can be accomplished using a `UIScrollView`.  When you've got a `UIImageView` embedded in a `UIScrollView`, it can perform the panning/zooming you mentioned in your question.

See `UIScrollView` documentation:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Also, here is a thread I found here on StackOverflow that lists several tutorials to help you get started:  [Are there any good UIScrollView Tutorials on the net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820557/are-there-any-good-uiscrollview-tutorials-on-the-net)