# UIScrollView with multiple images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

How to show current image in the scroll view along with some part of the next image if next image is available in the scroll view and also some part of the previous image if a previous image is available
 Like the pic attached here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This specific pattern makes me remind of [iCarousal](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).Check it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of UIScrollView with paging enabled in order to implement your requirements.

the following link  provides example for the same.

http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795

Here is the link that provides information on how to go about scrollView with paging enabled.

http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo for your scrollview effects.

[cover-flow-demo](http://code4app.net/ios/cover-flow-demo/5077958f6803fa2142000000)

[CoverFlow](http://code4app.net/ios/CoverFlow/50a34bdc6803fad569000000)

[HM-Customized-ScrollView](http://code4app.net/ios/HM-Customized-ScrollView/4fa36b1106f6e77d44000000)

Comment: i downloaded HMScrollView project but one class is missing in this project.so i am unable to see it actually what is there..If you have this project please send to my mail id :murali680555114@gmail.com

Comment: do you find those missing files?

Comment: yes, i find this class at heare http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/2_Autoscroll_Classes_TapDetectingImageView_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904-2_Autoscroll_Classes_TapDetectingImageView_h-DontLinkElementID_12

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code4app.net/ios/HM-Customized-ScrollView/4fa36b1106f6e77d44000000) is a good tutorial.Please find the same it will be useful for you

Hope this helps.

Comment: i downloaded this project but one class is missing in this project.so i am unable to see it actually what is there..If you have this project please send to my mail id :murali680555114@gmail.com

Comment: You can add me on skype at ashumishra224.I have also made the same project

Comment: if you fine any problem please find link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820557/are-there-any-good-uiscrollview-tutorials-on-the-net

Comment: I have sent you the project please find it on your id

Comment: Had you used HMScroolview in your project?

Comment: No I have implemented my own with page control

Comment: Link is broken.