# iOS : Swipe Gesture Push in one ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe, swipe-gesture

I want to add two swipe gesture. I did the code, and it's running, my text in the viewcontroller change when i touch the screen.

BUT, i want to add a "effect" when the user wants to slide at the next (or the previous) news, because currently, i'm just changing the text.

i tried to add action in the storyboard, to add push on the swipe with the view.

It's running, but there are two problems :

- The push, seems to have a problem, because, when i want to slide on the previous news, the push effect comes right to left. (and not left - right)
- I can't only change the contents without touch the navigation bar ? (because when i slide, the navigation bar loose him title, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you might want to use a UIScrollView. This will give you a nice animation.
You need a UIScrollView and add two of your ViewControllers as subviews.

Here are links to some ScollView tutorials:
[Are there any good UIScrollView Tutorials on the net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820557/are-there-any-good-uiscrollview-tutorials-on-the-net)

Comment: Absolutely not x) I want to be able to slide. For example, i have a news, and i want when i "slide" to right, an other news comes.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing on the navigation controller stack is to the right if you want to go back to opposite direction instead of pushing, you should pop like so: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` You could paste some code in your question :)

Comment: Sorry, i made an other post here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910409/add-effect-like-push-on-swipegesture?noredirect=1#comment33186209_21910409 i absolutely forgot this x)